# I need to clear out my Itunes library

Tags: mac, itunes, storage

My itunes library is being a space hog and I need to transfer unused files to an external hard-drive and/or compress them. Can someone tell me if:

a. that's possible

b. if itunes will play media on an external hard-drive

c. where itunes stores files(most of my stuff is from the itunes store).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer my own question.

I use the time machine utility to regularly backup my hard-drive and itunes has an option to open in finder. I checked the backup had a copy and just deleted stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a guide for moving your iTunes library to a different location.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1449